# Get value from object (stdClass)

Tags: php, json, stdclass

```
object(stdClass)#1 (8) { ["money_balance"]=> float(13.38)
["bitcoin_balance"]=> float(2.28448073) ["money_reserved"]=> float(0)    
["bitcoin_reserved"]=> float(2.28448073) ["money_available"]=> float(13.38)      
["bitcoin_available"]=> float(0) ["fee_percentage"]=> float(0.003)
["maker_fee_percentage"]=> float(0.0007) }
```

Hello. My JSON output as above. I want to get values from this. For example I want to get value of the "bitcoin_balance". I tried as below but not success.

```
$data->bitcoin_balance //not get
```

How can I get values from this?

Comment: Can you show us a bit more code? Like when you decode the JSON, etc.

Comment: What is in $data?

Comment: $data is my json variable

Comment: Based on what we see here and de example data being the result of var_dump, the $data->bitcoin_balance should just work. So, there's something else in the script which is giving some troubles